# Create dynamic overlapping divs which will change height based on inner content

Tags: html, css, css-position, division, overlapping

I want to create a structure in which there is a background container which will contain some image and will have some min-height. On top of that container there will be another container which will have some text content in it. Now if the text content increases, my parent container's height need to get increased.

I've implemented this using position:relative and absolute properties of css. The content div being absolute doesn't allow the parent div's height to get increased once the content increases.

Can I get some solutions for this. I don't want the change the existing implementation and need some fix in this one only.

I've created a dummy fiddle for this:

Thanks for helping..!!

```css
.parent{
          position:relative;
          min-height:300px;
          border:1px solid;
}
.child{
          position:absolute;
          width:200px;
          height:auto;
          border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/arpagrawal/kd144czz/1/

Comment: First of all, please format this properly. Your question is not _code_, so don’t format it as such.

Comment: so you want to keep this position absolute but still want the parent to increase height ? hmm don't think it's possible. and also will the image be an img or as background-image?

Comment: Why do you need an absolute positioned child? ... There is ways to position it like an absolute without using absolute.

Comment: Please review and comment on my answer, and let me know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few solution to this

1. use background-image and don't use position absolute . see snippet below

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/350x150');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
</div>
```

2. use jQuery to give the parent same height as child and use img tag

```js
$(".parent").height($(".child").height())
```

```css
.parent{
          position:relative;
          min-height:200px;
          border:1px solid;
}
.parent img {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;

}
.child{
          position:absolute;
          width:200px;
          height:auto;
          border:1px solid;
     top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <div class="child">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why the child must be absolute?
I don't see why it's necessary since the child is nested. If you add padding to the parent div that allows you to add as much content as you want to the child div without an overlap.

```
.parent {
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1em;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/350x150');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Here's an example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lfowler1290/t9s7raz3/)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably not your problem anymore however, I wanted to bring up an important issue here that will make position relative and absolute less than ideal. Position relative & absolute require a static height which you will have to update constantly in media queries to resemble some sort of dynamic height behavior. This is extremely hard to maintain because not all devices wrap paragraphs the same way.

When you deal with paragraphs, you must consider flexibility at all viewport sizes and responsive design. Paragraphs will change the div height dynamically as the paragraph wraps and creates new lines, therefore the paragraph's height will change. This will affect the items below your paragraph.

Here is a more dynamic solution using the grid display.

```
<div class="translate-parent">
   <div id="p_one" class="translate-child">
     <p> I AM PARAGRAPH 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
   </div>
   <div id="p-two" class="translate-child">
     <p> I AM PARAGRAPH 2 WITH LESS CONTENT, THUS LESS HEIGHT. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio. Tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

In your css do this:

```
.translate-parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100% 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100% 1fr;
}
.translate-child {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}
```

Here is a [**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/PodbdZY?editors=1111) showing you how a button below the paragraphs adjust according to the height of the elements above.